# Galaxy S6 Renderscript performance

Tags: samsung-mobile, galaxy, renderscript, mali

I have some problems with Renderscript. I did some test in order to evaluate the performance of Renderscript GPU compute. I used the ImageProcessing Renderscript Benchmark (android/platform/frameworks/rs/java/tests/ImageProcessing). I also used "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1" to force the script to run on CPU.

The execution time obtained are:

```
                                   GPU             CPU
Test Levels Vec3 Relaxed       13.594595ms      13.413333ms
Test Levels Vec4 Relaxed       14.4ms           14.027778ms
Test Levels Vec3 Full          14.594203ms      15.0ms
Test Levels Vec4 Full          15.227273ms      15.242424ms
Test Blur radius 25            388.0ms          379.66666ms
Test Intrinsic Blur radius 25  52.842106ms      52.1ms
Test Greyscale                 13.302631ms      13.493333ms
Test Grain                     136.25ms         137.5ms
Test Fisheye Full              57.61111ms       59.235294ms
Test Fisheye Relaxed           59.764706ms      57.055557ms
Test Fisheye Approximate Full  54.473682ms      58.555557ms
Test Fisheye Approx Relaxed    58.555557ms      55.833332ms
Test Vignette Full             28.885714ms      27.86111ms
Test Vignette Relaxed          29.028572ms      28.166666ms
Test Vignette Approximate Full 22.288889ms      21.680851ms
Test Vignette Approx Relaxed   21.553192ms      21.76087ms
Test Group Test (emulated)     6.4166665ms      6.429487ms
Test Group Test (native)       6.335443ms       6.3757963ms
Test Convolve 3x3              38.653847ms      39.423077ms
Test Intrinsics Convolve 3x3   4.2777777ms      4.3608694ms
...
```

The CPU and GPU executions do not show any differences. It looks like the S6 device always choose the CPU instead of the GPU. I executed the same tests in other devices and the GPU execution is quite faster than the CPU.

Is the ARM mali Renderscript driver included into the S6 device?